# JAVA - How to get last/recently CREATED folder name in a directory?

Tags: java

How to get the last created (not last modified) folder name/path in a directory using JAVA? I could not find answers related to JAVA, hence posting here.

Comment: Here are steps: (1) get the list of all names/paths in the directory, (2) order them in descending order of creation date, (3) choose first one in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a few steps, for example:

1. list all elements of a directory
2. filter for directories
3. get file creation time
4. save up the path + time combo in a list
5. find the minimum of the list with respect of time

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LastCreatedDir {

    record PathAndTime(Path path, FileTime time) { }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Path path = Paths.get("..\\");
        List<PathAndTime> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // 1. -------------------------------------
        try (var files = Files.list(path)) {
            files.forEach(p -> {
                // 2. -----------------------------
                if (Files.isDirectory(p)) {
                    try {
                        // 3. -----------------------
                        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(p,
                            BasicFileAttributes.class);
                        FileTime fileTime = attr.creationTime();

                        // 4. -----------------------
                        list.add(new PathAndTime(p, fileTime));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // 5. -------------------------------------        
        var result = list.stream().min((a, b) -> {
            return b.time.compareTo(a.time);
        });
        
        result.ifPresentOrElse(entry -> {
            System.out.println(entry.path + " @ " + entry.time);
        }, () -> {
            System.out.println("No directories found");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I need only the Creation date and not the time?

Comment: Use `LocalDate` as store and `LocalDate.ofInstant(fileTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault​()))`